# Recaptcha allowing spam

Tags: php, recaptcha, spam

I made a site for someone which has a contact form, but they said they're getting a lot of spam.

I added recaptcha V2, but it's still getting spammed.

```
    // other conditions to see if all fields were filled in come before this
} elseif($_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]=="") {
        $message="Please verify that you are human.";
} else {
    $data = array(
        'secret' => $secret,
        'response' => $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"],
    );
    $context = stream_context_create(array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => 'POST',
            'content' => http_build_query($data),
        ),
    ));

    $verification = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify', false, $context);
    $verification = json_decode($verification);
    $verified = $verification->success;

    if (!$verified) {
        $message="Error. You don't seem to be human! If this seems like a mistake, you can give us a ring at {$phone}.";
    } else {
        // sanitize input & send email
    }
```

Client-side integration shouldn't be the problem because I just copied/pasted what google gave ._.

Also, when I go to the recaptcha website, google tells me:

> We detected that your site is verifying reCAPTCHA passed solutions
>   less than 50% of the time. This could indicate a problem with your
>   integration with reCAPTCHA. Please see our developer site for more
>   information.

Any ideas of what's going wrong?

Comment: Use  (false === $verified) instead of (!$verified)

Comment: @Juan why so? the first one will work too

Comment: Try `var_dump($verified)` and test a load of times, see what happens when you do and don't tick the box etc. Also I don't agree with @Juan's suggestion. It should be fine as it is (although could throw a warning if not set) (and I also hate yoda conditions, just saying)

Comment: Do a `var_dump($verification)` too to see the whole response, also, you don't have to create the `$verified` variable you can use `$verification->success` directly, unnecessary waste of resources.

Comment: Depending on the content of $verified (!$verified) could evaluate to missleading results. By using false === $verified, you make sure $verified is a boolean and, in this case, it's value is false.

Comment: @Juan The Google's API returns a boolean value. So `success` will either have `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

Comment: @Juan are you saying this could be other than (bool) true/false? ie null or unset? Given the issue is 50% of the time, dumping it a number of times will reveal if it's ever a problem or not

Comment: $verified depends on $verification, which is a json_decode of the result of get_file_contents, which is a connection over https. There are no validations in the middle. If everything goes fine you should have a boolean and everything said in other comments applies. If something goes wrong, and you don't end up with a boolean, no error will be thrown because !$variable is a valid evalualtion, but can have many meanings depending on the content of the $variable. You should var_dump as @James says to see what you are getting back. Mine is just a sugestion that will save you time in the long run.